# Convert .rdata to .sas7bdat or .sav

Tags: r, sas, spss

I have an R dataset (an .Rdata file) that I need to convert to either SAS (.sas7bdat or .xpt) or SPSS (.sav or .por).  How can I import this dataset into SAS or SPSS?

Comment: Have you tried the `foreign` package?

Comment: I'm not completely sure. I literally don't understand what I'm doing. I think I did, but it was unsuccesful. I was able to convert to a CSV, but when I converted it to SPSS, it didn't translate well.

Comment: Do you have SAS/IML installed?

Comment: just write as a csv or tab delimited

Comment: Why do you need it in those formats? What are you trying to do? (Also, Stat/Transfer is ideal for these things, if you have a license for it.)

Comment: I need it in another format because I don't know how to use R. I am working on a collaborative research project.

Comment: I've edited the question in an attempt to make it a valid question for this site.  As it stood it was certainly not one.  You should edit it further to add anything you've tried and need help with.

Comment: Thanks! My question was answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this in SPSS, consider using the STATS_GETR extension command.  It can read R workspace or data files and map appropriate elements directly to an SPSS dataset.  This extension command is available from the SPSS Community (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) website or, for Statistics 22, it can be installed via the Utilities menu.

Comment: Will I able to do that using SPSS remotely via my University's server?